# Column ordering (language specific) and collation confusion (MySQL) in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using MySQL and on the database collation is set to "utf8_slovenian_ci".
Table in question is also set to use this same collation.

Then, in database.yml the configuration is also like this:

```
encoding: utf8
collation: utf8_slovenian_ci
```

Now, when i do an order in Rails application, order is wrong, in MySQL is correct if i use `...ORDER BY column COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci;`

Is it possible to use COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci inside rails order queries? What do collate and encoding in database.yml actually do, if not tell excately this?

Main problem and a question is how o order by language specific characters in Rails with MySQL.

Comment: Are you able to be involved in the original table creation?

Comment: Yes, no problem there.

Comment: Ok, then I am not saying the following reference is speaking to your question 100%, but look at what I wrote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37649531) for table creates at the column level