# Selected columns dont have compatiable type, even it has same type

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I am creating FOREIGN KEY on Table1(propType) from Table2 with groupName. But i am facing below error. 
selected columns dont have compatiable type , even it has same type in mysql

Table 1 :

```
    CREATE TABLE `configuration_master` (
      `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `insertTimestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `propName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `propValue` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `propType` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `IsCloudSupport` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `DisplayName` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `updateTimestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `userId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `SYNCCOL1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `SYNCCOL2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `SYNCCOL3` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `SYNCCOL4` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `SYNCCOL5` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `SYNCCOL6` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `SYNCCOL7` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `SYNCCOL8` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `SYNCCOL9` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `SYNCCOL10` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `prptyp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `propName` (`propName`),
      KEY `FKB54491EB8E326E43` (`userId`),
      KEY `proptype_frn_idx` (`propType`),
      KEY `ASD_idx` (`prptyp`),
      CONSTRAINT `FKB54491EB8E326E43` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user_master` (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=86 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Table2:

```
    CREATE TABLE `config_group` (
      `groupName` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
      `prop1` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `prop2` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `prop3` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `prop4` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `ADS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `config_groupcol` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`groupName`),
      UNIQUE KEY `config_groupcol_UNIQUE` (`config_groupcol`),
      UNIQUE KEY `ADS_UNIQUE` (`ADS`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I am creating FOREIGN KEY as below

```
    ALTER TABLE `konysyncconsoledb7214dev`.`configuration_master` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_configGrop`
      FOREIGN KEY (`propType`)
      REFERENCES `konysyncconsoledb7214dev`.`config_group` (`groupName`)
```

Below image is error msg. if any faced this issue plz let me know what i am missing.
[image: error msg]

Comment: Don't forget to upvote, downvote, accept answers if appropriate. It is our feedback, and cheers us on to help the next guy.

Answer (score 7):

From the mysql manual page found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same.

Your issue was the collation. I had no problem creating the following whatsoever. Note that I had to ditch your db name from part of it.

Oh, and since you did not provide the third table, I had to remove that FK constraint. But that is not the issue.

Note, nullability was not the issue.

What you decide to do about your collation choices is up to you. But that was it.

```
CREATE TABLE `configuration_master` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `insertTimestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `propName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `propValue` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `propType` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsCloudSupport` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `DisplayName` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `updateTimestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `userId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SYNCCOL1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SYNCCOL2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SYNCCOL3` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SYNCCOL4` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SYNCCOL5` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SYNCCOL6` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SYNCCOL7` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SYNCCOL8` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SYNCCOL9` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SYNCCOL10` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `prptyp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `propName` (`propName`),
  KEY `FKB54491EB8E326E43` (`userId`),
  KEY `proptype_frn_idx` (`propType`),
  KEY `ASD_idx` (`prptyp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;



 CREATE TABLE `config_group` (
  `groupName` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `prop1` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `prop2` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `prop3` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `prop4` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `config_groupcol` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`groupName`),
  UNIQUE KEY `config_groupcol_UNIQUE` (`config_groupcol`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ADS_UNIQUE` (`ADS`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;   

ALTER TABLE  `configuration_master` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_configGrop`
  FOREIGN KEY (`propType`)
  REFERENCES `config_group` (`groupName`);
```

### More detail of your Original

This addresses the comment from Barmar. Your create table for `config_group` caused a discrepancy for matching collations for the FK to succeed with the `ALTER TABLE` . Manual page for [SHOW FULL COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html)

From the Manual Page [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-column.html):

> If CHARACTER SET X is specified without COLLATE, character set X and
>   its default collation are used.
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1
> (
>     col1 CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8
> ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin;
> ```
>
> The character set is specified for the column, but the collation is
>   not. The column has character set utf8 and the default collation for
>   utf8, which is utf8_general_ci. To see the default collation for each
>   character set, use the SHOW COLLATION statement.

[image]

Comment: Setting `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` in the table options doesn't automatically set it for the `groupName` column?

Comment: @Barmar I hope the block at the bottom that I added illustrates the issue. The block is entitled "More detail of your Original".

Comment: Do you know why it's ignoring `COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci` on the last line? Isn't that supposed to set the default collation for any columns that don't have their own `COLLATE` option?

Comment: @Barmar Here is the reason why [image](http://i.imgur.com/AXTroBP.jpg) from Manual page [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-column.html)

Comment: Ahh, so it's because he specified the `CHARACTER SET` for the column, so it uses the default collation for the character set, instead of the default collation for the table. So another solution would be to remove `CHARACTER SET utf8` from the column, since that's the table default.

Answer (score 1):

propType is by default NULL, but groupName CANNOT be NULL. This could be your issue.

```
`propType` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL

`groupName` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
```

But I may be wrong. Try looking over these guidelines and ensuring your FK constraint follows all of them:

1. Both tables must be InnoDB type.
2. In the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.
3. Index prefixes on foreign key columns are not supported.
4. InnoDB needs indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.
5. The two key fields must have the compatible field type.
6. The size and the sign of integer types has to be the same.
7. The length of string types need not be the same.
8. The foreign key name must be unique within the database
9. If you specify a SET NULL action, make sure that you have not declared the columns in the child table as NOT NULL.

(From here: http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/Why_I_cannot_successfully_create_the_foreign_keys%3F)

Comment: Even Table1 has Not Null for propType , it didnt worked

Comment: Then there must be something else that your FK constraint doesn't adhere to in the list. Later, when I can try these table creation scripts on my own, I may be able to help you if another person hasn't come by with a solution. :)