# MySQL utf8mb4 in Codeship

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, codeship

I'm running automated tests for a Rails app in Codeship, and I'd like to use `utf8mb4` as the database encoding.

Here's my modified `database.yml`:

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  pool: 10
  username: <%= ENV['MYSQL_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I followed this tutorial: https://codeship.com/documentation/databases/mysql/ , but the encoding is still `utf8`.

How can I run the tests using a `utf8mb4` encoding for the database?

Comment: On the create table statements specify CHARSET and collation. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37649531