# mySQL: What is preventing my foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have tried everything I can think of but I am still having problems creating a table.

I have a user table with a primary key `username`

`+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| created_at    | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at    | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| username      | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| administrator | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fullname      | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| description   | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| password      | varchar(60) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

and I want to create a new table like this:

`CREATE TABLE sessions (
  created_at DATETIME, 
  updated_at DATETIME, 
  token VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  username VARCHAR(50), 
  PRIMARY KEY (token), 
  FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES users (username)
);`

but I get a nasty error:

`ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint`

I usually find this error is caused by a mismatch in the data type of the pk/fk pair but this time both are clearly `varchar(50)` so it looks like the problem is elsewhere.

I have also tried this just in case:

`CREATE TABLE sessions (
  created_at DATETIME, 
  updated_at DATETIME, 
  token VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  username varchar(50) NOT NULL, #<- ***added not null***
  PRIMARY KEY (token), 
  FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES users (username)
);`

`mysql>SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

> LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
>
> 2016-08-03 15:13:23 a46fcb70 Error in foreign key constraint of table savesdev/sessions:
>   FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES users (username)):
>   Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
>   referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
>   in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
>   Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
>   tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
>   cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
>   See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>   for correct foreign key definition.

It seems the error is raised under two circumstances:

1) When there is a mismatch (which I have ruled out)

> column types in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.

2) When there is no suitable index on the referenced column

> Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns

I think both of these are covered so what's the deal?

Can anyone spot my error?

Comment: `show engine innodb status`. about 1/2 through the dump will be a "last foreign key error" section, with details. Most likely you have a field definition mismatch. FK relations have to be identical, e.g. `varchar(49) -> varchar(50)` isn't allowed, but `varchar(50)->varchar(50)` is. or you're on an older mysql which doesn't auto-create indexes on FK fields, and you haven't manually added a key on username.

Comment: Maybe your columns username have different charset can you try this  : ALTER TABLE sessions MODIFY username VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY username VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;

Comment: That's a good point @elkorchianas, I will have a look..

Comment: Yes, correct! Could you add an answer? referencing this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4805510/1083707 or I can.

Comment: It is similar to [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37649531) and perhaps my [Describe all Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38693720) can help at times too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe your columns username have different charset can you try this :

```
ALTER TABLE sessions MODIFY username VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8; 
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY username VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

As suggested by @Graeme Stuart here is a link to see how we can check the charterer set of a database / table or a column  : [How do I see what character set a MySQL database / table / column is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-mysql-database-table-column-is/4805510#4805510)

Comment: Yes, the fields were both VARCHAR(50) but the existing table had a utf8_general_ci collation which made them incompatable. My actual solution was to create the new table with utf8_general_ci collation for the foreign key column.